# Vaadin 14 Layout on iPhone 11 and later not showing complete

Tags: iphone, vaadin

We have an app using spring boot. Works fine under Android or desktop.

When using an iPhone (we have tested it with iPhone 11 and 13), the layout width does not show complete, it is trimmed on both sides, it shows as if it would not fit on the apple screen. We have no issues with the height of the layout.

The base layout is a VerticalLayout, we set the size with setSizeFull();

[iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMOe5.jpg)
[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp9kj.jpg)

Comment: A screenshot would help a lot in understanding the issue.

Comment: Please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)